# How to set time delay to error messages in android app with kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am currently creating an android app with AndroidStudio and `kotlin`. I have reached the point that I have created a Log in Activity and I have the code below inside a function in a `kotlin class`:

```
Username.error = null
val emailStr = Username.text.toString()

var cancel = false
var focusView: View? = null

if (TextUtils.isEmpty(emailStr)) {
        Username.error = getString(R.string.error_field_required) //Username is the name of the editText in the layout xml file
        focusView = Username
        cancel = true
    } else if (!isEmailValid(emailStr)) {
        Username.error = getString(R.string.error_invalid_email)
        focusView = Username
        cancel = true
    }

if (cancel) {
    //If there was an error don't attempt login and focus the form field with an error.
    focusView?.requestFocus()
}
```

The code works fine with one exeption. The error message that appears stays on until I tap inside the text area. My problem is that it covers some other things so I would like to make it disappear after lets say 3 seconds. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With androidx you can do this to remove the error after three seconds:

```
//create a handler as class variable
val handler = Handler()

/in your method:
if (cancel) {    
    handler.postDelayed(3000){Username.error = null}
    focusView?.requestFocus()
}
```

without androidx:

```
if (cancel) {    
    handler.postDelayed({Username.error = null}, 3000)
    focusView?.requestFocus()
}
```

Comment: I tried the second one and it did not seem to work the message stayed on

Comment: Also I think that in order to work it would requier that `focusView` is equal to `null` and not `Username.error` but still didn't word

Comment: I tested it in an example app, it works, with or without focusView. see https://github.com/leokraemer/stackoverflowExampleApps/blob/master/app/src/main/java/kraemer/leonard/de/myapplication/MainActivity.kt for the code. Maybe you have some other code that triggers the error message again.

Comment: Yep it worked I was syntaxing it wrong thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how the error message is displayed, but if it is removed by setting it to null you could do something like this in the `if(cancel)`

```
if (cancel) {
    focusView?.requestFocus()
    launch() { //new thread so we don't lock the UI
        delay(3000) //wait 3000 ms
        Username.error = null
    }
}
```

Comment: A coroutine is not a new thread and does run on the ui thread (although `launch()` does not block the thread when the coroutine suspends).

Comment: I get an error `unresolved reference` for `delay` and `launch` are there any libraries that I need to include in order for it to work?

Comment: you have to include coroutines for this

Comment: @leonardkraemer Sorry to ask but how do I include coroutins i looked it up and didn't undrestand much